# Sending info immediately to database whenever textarea value changes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a textarea.. I just want to send the textarea value whenever it changes to the database..I have tried something..But it's not working out..Can anyone help here?

Index.php

```
<textarea id="cap'.$id.'"></textarea>
```

AJAX

```
    var i = <?php echo $id; ?>  
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#cap"+i).keyup(function(){
    var cap =  $("#cap"+i).text($(this).val());

    $.post('send.php', {cap:cap, i:i}, function(data){


            }); 
                 });
    });
```

send.php

```
$cap = $_POST['cap'];


if($cap){

if($cap == ""){
$cap = "Caption Not Given Yet";
}

$sql = mysql_query('UPDATE table SET caption="'.$cap.'" WHERE id="'.(int)$_POST['i'].'"')or die(mysql_error());


}
```

It's not working...

Comment: <<It's not working...>> means?

Comment: it's not sending the value to the database table whenever the value in textarea changes...

Comment: Check your DOM, isn't it the id of textarea not what you expect it to be?

Comment: not an answer to your question, but are you sure you want to update the database on a key-up event? This means that if someone can type quite fast, your database will be updated a 120 times every minute. When 10 people do that on the same time... Maybe a blur event is good enough?

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
var cap =  $("#cap"+i).text($(this).val());
```

to

```
var cap =  $(this).val();
```

Comment: it's working..but not for series of textarea which has their own rows in a table..only the last value gets updated